# How to link two different visual studio projects?

Tags: c, database

Let's say we have project A and project B created using Visual Studio. What is the proper way for project B to have access in real time of values of project A ?
For example the way I was using until now was to use an SQL database to connect those two projects by passing values from project A to the SQL database and then project B have access to those values from the SQL database. But the thing is that the whole program( a simulator that uses these two .dlls from the projects) was getting really slow over time because the SQL database was increasing.